# Error building NodeJS when implementing a React Design System

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, docker, jsx

I've built out a design system using react components. In this design system I've also placed common typing and I want to utilize these in my NodeJS project. When installing the design system through npm it works fine locally, but when pushing the code and the build is run in TeamCity with Docker, then these errors are presented.

```
[11:58:23][docker] node_modules/...: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.
[11:58:23][docker] node_modules/...: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-select/src/filters' or its corresponding type declarations.
[11:58:23][docker] node_modules/...: error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'JSX'.
```

The inclusion of a design system in NodeJS is a little foreign to me, so may be some small thing i've overlooked, but I couldn't find a solution when I tried to Google the problem.

Comment: are you using typescript? if yes then try adding @types/react for the packages.

Comment: @RahulSharma Thanks, that worked. This slipped my mind as all these node_modules are in the design system. You could answer with that solution, and I'll set it as the correct answer.